# Importação de biblioteca Excel para VB.NET no Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vb.net

Em um projeto Web em VB.NET no Visual Studio realizei a importação de uma biblioteca para geração de arquivos Excel. (No menu Ferramentas --> Extensões e Atualizações).

Realizei a importação na página desejada (Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) e consegui utilizá-la normalmente e corretamente.

Porém, ao enviar meu projeto para o servidor (Compilação --> Publicar nomedoprojeto), o sistema é atualizado corretamente, sem erros, porém a biblioteca não funciona na versão online do meu sistema. O botão que deveria gerar o arquivo .xlsx, que funciona localmente, na versão online não funciona.

Alguma ideia que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Dá algum erro ao executar o código do botão?

Comment: Nemhum erro. Somente nada é executado.